# Show that $S$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, matrices, compactness

Let $A \in M_n(\bf C)$ and let 
 $S=\{ A \in M_n(\bf C) : A=A ^*$ and  $\rho (A) \leq 1 \}$, $\rho(A)$ denotes spectral radius of $A$.

> Show that $S$ is compact subset of $M_n(\bf C) \cong \bf C^{n^2} $ with usual topology.

$S$ is subset of $\bf O_n(C)$ which is compact so I think its enough to show that $S$ is closed.Please help.

Comment: Use the fact that $\rho$ is continuous.

Comment: @Crostul  Do you mean that $S$ is preimage of $(-\infty,1]$  under $\rho$ ?

Comment: Yes. In this case, it is quite obvious that it is closed.

Comment: How is $S$ subset of $O_n(C)$?

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal  Its not actually,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the hermitian matrices we have $||A||= \rho(A)$ and $\rho$ is given bounded , thus the set is bounded and since $\rho$ is a continuous map, inverse image of $(-\infty,1]$ is closed and thus your set is closed too. So it is compact.

Comment: Is it obvious that $||A||= \rho(A)$  for $A$ hermitian?

Comment: Ah,I see it by Spectral Theorem.How do you see it?